# Gitlab Runner on AWS becomes really slow after some time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using Gitlab shared runner with Docker (current runner version: 10.0.2, docker storage driver: overlay2), running on AWS t2.small instance. I started experiencing issues with builds slowing down after some time (it's hard to say when exactly they become slow) - they take ~10x more time to finish than before. After killing the instance problem disappears for a while and after some time it slows down again.

Things I already checked:

- CPU usage on machine is around 20% the whole time
- RAM usage is around 1,5 G during the heaviest build
- IOPS on EBS are not exhausting all Burst Balance (e.g. right now burst balance is around 80%)
- Download speed

What else might be causing this ?

Just in case, jobs that are running on this runner are mostly `yarn install` and `yarn build` of a medium-sized front-end React application.

Answer (score 0):

You mention you're using a t2.small, what's the CPU credit balance on your instance when you see this slow-down?

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html#t2-instances-cpu-credits
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html#t2-instances-monitoring-cpu-credits

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I mentioned in my post, CPU usage is constantly around 20% and it doesn't use any CPU credits as I checked in CloudWatch metrics so that's probably not the case.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using any CPU credits? You state that your CPU utilization is a constant 20%. Reading the T2 documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html#t2-instances-cpu-credits) that would correspond to using 1 CPU credit every 5 minutes. A t2.small gets 12 CPU credits/hour (https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t2/) so if you ever burst above 20% constant CPU utilization you'd start using more CPU credits than allocated and thus likely see a slow down.